# Podcast Guest List

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, podcasting

So what I want to do is too have a function similar to a category or tag, but a little more robust.

It's **for a podcast** to *list of guests for each episode*.

Ideally this would do a few things:

#### Guest Data

For *each* guest (added to an episode), display their:

- name,
- photo,
- twitter id,
- url.

#### Guest Page

Clicking on their photo or name would the visitor to a page *like the authors page*, where more info on that guest could be stored:

- a short bio,
- all the episodes that guest has appeared on,
- etc...

#### Meta Box on pod cast edit screen:

The management of this would ideally be managed like categories are now, through checkboxes and names listed on the write page to select from. Further management, (adding bio, photos, ect) would be done in another panel like posts are.

My first thought was custom post types or custom taxonomies, but I'm not sure which method is more feasible. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did was make a custom post type for guests profiles, and use "posts 2 posts" to connect them to specific episodes. The plugin has functions to both list the connected guests on episode pages, and list all episodes associated with that guest on their profile pages.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom post type and a taxonomy.

There is a great tutorial over on Justin Tadlocks website that uses movies as an example but you could translate this to podcast.

[Post types and taxonomies: Linking terms to a specific post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/08/20/linking-terms-to-a-specific-post)

Comment: I was reading that last night, and in the comments there seems to be a bit of confusion as to whether or not this is the best method to attack this problem. Specifically, how to display a list of "guests" with photo and other data, on the episodes page, and not just the plain link tags.

Comment: Is podcast already a CPT ? You could maybe get away with using post meta and a meta box on the CPT listing the guests. This would assume you have already entered the guests prior to the podcast though. Which _might_ work. The issue with Tadlocks tutorial and with this problem is how to give a relationship between the CPT & the taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/powerpress/). There are also paid upgrades but it looks promising.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the issue I'm trying to solve with guest's on specific episodes.

Comment: Then maybe you should describe your problem more in detail withmaybe a real world example. And define "guest".

Comment: Essentially, I want to add a list of who is on each episode of the show, and be able to link to and display that guests page with a listing of episodes they appear on.

Comment: Ok, again: What is a "guest"? Ask yourself some questions. For eg.: May a "guest" publish posts? (= Which role & capabilities are needed?), Does a "guest" need a login at all (= is he just data or a real person interacting with the system?), What exact sort of data is attached to a "guest"? (= Is it a user, taxonomy, post or is a custom post type needed or do you need to extend user profiles?). And so on. Please update your Q with as many Q/As as possible to give us more insights into your target.

Comment: Think of the "guest" as an item, rather then a user. A guest is a fancy way of saying the person who's voice was captured on that episode. We don't need to create accounts for them or anything like that, just be able to tag them on posts and display their information.

Comment: If so, then you're best of with a custom post type. There you can add any information of any kind. You'd still have to figure out how to add a) a meta box that lists all custom post types of "guest" and b) how to display them in your template.